# How can I make Jenkins CI with Git trigger on pushes to master?

Tags: git, github, jenkins

I'm trying to set up Jenkins-ci for a project using GitHub. I've already set up Jenkins with the appropriate plugins. I want Jenkins to run build scripts only whenever someone on the project pushes to master. So far I've been able to set it up so that a build will be triggered anytime anyone pushes to anywhere, but that is too broad. I've done this with post-receive service hooks on Git.

I've read the Jenkins wiki, and a couple of tutorials, but this particular detail is missing... is it something to do with polling maybe? Or should work be done on the Git side, so that Git only triggers Jenkins when `master` is changed?

Comment: The original author of Jenkins, Kohsuke Kawaguchi, describes how to do push-notification from the repository using the Git plugin Git plugin 1.1.14. See http://kohsuke.org/2011/12/01/polling-must-die-triggering-jenkins-builds-from-a-git-hook/

Answer (score 198, accepted):

As already noted by *gezzed* in his comment, meanwhile there is a good solution (described in *[Polling must die: triggering Jenkins builds from a Git hook](http://kohsuke.org/2011/12/01/polling-must-die-triggering-jenkins-builds-from-a-git-hook/)*):

- Set the Jenkins job's build trigger to *Poll SCM*, but do *not* specify a schedule.
- Create a GitHub post-receive trigger to notify the URL

  ```
  http://yourserver/jenkins/git/notifyCommit?url=<URL of the Git repository>?token=<get token from git to build remotely>
  ```
- This will trigger all builds that poll the specified Git repository.
- However, polling actually checks whether anything has been pushed to the used branch.

It works perfectly.

Comment: This worked great for me as well, you can use the same approach with a local gitorious install: http://cweiske.de/tagebuch/gitorious-post-receive-hook-2.htm

Comment: Works with Bitbucket's POST hook (not Jenkins) as well.

To specify authentication credentials, you can use http://user:password@my.ci.server/git/notifyCommit?url=... as the URL.

Comment: Can it be configured so jenkins builds only the libs/projects affected by the latest push to the repo? Not building the whole branch again?

Comment: Can you clarify this part? "Create a github post-receive trigger to notify the URL"

Comment: I assume that github has to be able to reach your Jenkins instance, meaning it had to be publicly accessible. Is it possible to get this working with a Jenkins server that is non-public?

Comment: That depends on how "non-public" the server is. If you mean that the server is in an intranet behind a firewall and cannot be reached from the internet, then this won't work.
If, however, the Jenkins instance is reachable but not everyone should be able to trigger a build, then you can solve this via the token of the hook: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42817169/jenkins-trigger-builds-remotely-authentication-token-option-missing

Comment: You might also be able to create a privileged proxy which is accessible from the internet, and which has a privileged path to your otherwise-private Jenkins -- a VPN, an SSH tunnel, a whitelisted IP, whatever works for your organization.

Answer (score 34):

As of version 0.5, the GitHub plugin for Jenkins can [trigger a build when a change is pushed to GitHub](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Github+Plugin#GithubPlugin-TriggerabuildwhenachangeispushedtoGitHub).

Comment: @asveikau -- The original question was about github.

Comment: That's not a good solution because it triggers the build regardless of which branch was pushed.

Comment: Actually, it looks like it obeys the branch specifier in the git plugin settings if you enable "Poll SCM" (no schedule necessary).

Comment: While that might be true, it still triggers the build incorrectly when no workspace exists ("Workspace is offline.
Scheduling a new build to get a workspace. (nonexisting_workspace)
Done. Took 0 ms
Changes found"). See also https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-18079

Comment: The [GitHub plugin lists the Git plugin as a dependency](https://plugins.jenkins.io/github). The [wiki](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/GitHub+Plugin#GitHubPlugin-Hyperlinksbetweenchanges) says "when creating a job, specify URL under "Github project" and select Git specify URL under "Source Code Management".
It says "This trigger only kicks Git plugin internal polling algo for every incoming event against matched repo." I think that means it pretty much does the Poll SCM like in the accepted answer, but it has options to set up the webhook automatically and a couple other features.

Answer (score 9):

Instead of triggering *builds* remotely, change your Jenkins project configuration to trigger builds by polling.

Jenkins can poll based on a fixed internal, or by a URL.  The latter is what you want to skip builds if there are not changes for that branch. The exact details are 
in [the documentation](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project#Buildingasoftwareproject-Buildsbysourcechanges). Essentially you just need to check the "Poll SCM" option, leave the schedule section blank, and set a remote URL to hit JENKINS_URL/job/name/polling.

One gotcha if you have a secured Jenkins environment is unlike `/build`, the `/polling` URL requires authentication. The instructions [here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Authenticating+scripted+clients) have details.  For example, I have a GitHub Post-Receive hook going to `username:apiToken@JENKIS_URL/job/name/polling`.

Answer (score 8):

For **GitLab**, use these steps:

1. Go to your project's settings → Web hooks
2. Enter the "Build Now" URL from your Jenkins project as a Push Event URL:

   `http://server.com/jenkins/job/project_name/build?delay=0sec` for example
3. Click `Add Web Hook` and then `test hook`

Then any time you commit to the repository, the web hook is triggered and a build is created. Be sure to set your Jenkins workspace to `delete workspace before each build` so you get a fresh copy of the new code.

Comment: how are you solving the problem on the question regarding to build just when the push on master branch?

Answer (score 4):

Not related to Git, but below I will help with the Jenkins job configuration in detail with Mercurial. It may help others with a similar problem.

1. Install the URL Trigger Plugin
2. Go to the job configuration page and select `Poll SCM` option. Set the value to `* * * * *`
3. Check the option: `[URLTrigger] - Poll with a URL`.
   Now you can select some options like modification date change, URL content, etc.
4. In the options, select URL content change, select first option – `Monitor change of content`
5. Save the changes.

Now, trigger some change to the Mercurial repository by some test check-ins.

See that the Jenkins job now runs by detecting the SCM changes. When the build is run due to Mercurial changes, then, you will see text `Started by an SCM change`. Else, the user who manually started it.

Answer (score 4):

I hope this helps: *[How to trigger a Jenkins build on Git commit](http://nrecursions.blogspot.in/2014/02/how-to-trigger-jenkins-build-on-git.html)*

It's just a matter of using curl to trigger a Jenkins job using the Git hooks provided by Git.

The command `curl http://localhost:8080/job/someJob/build?delay=0sec` can run a Jenkins job, where `someJob` is the name of the Jenkins job.

Search for the "hooks" folder in your hidden .git folder. Rename the "post-commit.sample" file to "post-commit". Open it with Notepad, remove the ": Nothing" line and paste the above command into it.

That's it. Whenever you do a commit, Git will trigger the post-commit commands defined in the file.

Comment: I was confused here with your comment at first because, I thought I had to change the "job" in the url above to a job name.  I was also confused because when I pressed "New Item" in Jenkins, I set up a "Project" not a job, so when you referenced "someJob" above, I did not know that that was the name of my project.

I finally figured out the url I needed: http://localhost:8078/job/codecept%20tests/build  where "codecept%20tests" was the name of my project.  Thanks for your solution

Comment: Thanks Paul. I've updated the blog post with an additional note, mentioning your solution. The "%20" will especially be helpful to others.

Answer (score 4):

Continuous Integration with Jenkins, after code is pushed to repository from Git command/ GUI:

1. Create a job in Jenkins with only job name and select type of the project freestyle. Click <kbd>OK</kbd>. The next page doesn't add anything - just click <kbd>Save</kbd>.
2. Go to the your local Git repository where you have the source code and navigate to the `.git/hooks` folder.
3. The `hooks` folder contains the few files. Check for the "post-commit". If not present, create a file, "post-commit" without a file extension:

   ```
   C:\work\test\\.git\hooks\post-commit
   ```
4. Edit the "post-commit" file with the below command. Make sure it is present in your local source code hooks folder.

   ```
   curl -u userName:apiToken -X POST http://localhost:8080/jenkins/job/jobName/build?token=apiToken
   ```

   Example:

   ```
   curl -u admin:f1c55b3a07bb2b69b9dd549e96898384 -X POST http://localhost:8080/jenkins/job/Gitcommittest/build?token=f1c55b3a07bb2b69b9dd549e96898384
   ```

   5.

   `userName`: Jenkins user name

   `jobName`: Job name of the build

   `apiToken`: To get your API token, go to your Jenkins user page (top right in the interface). It is available in the "Configure" menu on the left of the page: "Show API token"
5. Make changes in your source code and commit the code to repository.
6. Your job, `http://localhost:8080/jenkins/job/Gitcommittest/`, should be building.

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify the branch. By default it listens to anything. See the blog post *[Hudson: Git and Maven plugins](http://evgenyg.wordpress.com/2010/03/27/hudson-git-maven/)*.

Comment: I've recently setup Jenkins at work to pull changes from git on a specified branch. Works fine. +1

Comment: I have set that setting as well. What I am noticing is that Jenkins is notified of each and every push to github, and reacts to it, but only runs the build steps if branch master has changed. So we get a ton of spurious build reports that say "No Changes". Are you observing this behavior as well?

Comment: The original question is about how to solve the broad and unnecessary trigger (triggering when anyone pushes on any branch) configured in your answer. If you have 5 jenkin jobs with the same config except that the first job listen master branch, the second the devel branch, the third the  FeatureX branch and so on, when you only push to FeatureX branch all jenkins jobs will be triggered what leading to work overload with builds very slow.

Answer (score 3):

[Generic Webhook Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Generic+Webhook+Trigger+Plugin) can be configured with filters to achieve this.

When configured with

- A variable named `ref` and expression `$.ref`.
- A filter with text `$ref` and filter expression like `^refs/heads/master$`.

Then that job will trigger for every push to `master`. No polling.

You probably want more values from the webhook to actually perform the build. Just add more variables, with JSONPath, to pick what you need.

There are some use cases here: https://github.com/jenkinsci/generic-webhook-trigger-plugin/tree/master/src/test/resources/org/jenkinsci/plugins/gwt/bdd

Comment: What is *"achi"*?

Comment: It is/was a spelling mistake.

Comment: how do you grab the $GITCOMMIT in Jenkins, it always seems to be null with a webhook. Can't then send the status back to say success or failed.

Answer (score 1):

In my current organization, we don't do this in master but do do it on both develop and release/ branches (we are using Git Flow), in order to generate snapshot builds.

As we are using a multi branch pipeline, we do this in the Jenkinsfile with the *when{}* syntax...

```
stage {
    when { 
        expression { 
            branch 'develop'
        }
    }
}
```

This is detailed in this blog post:
https://jenkins.io/blog/2017/01/19/converting-conditional-to-pipeline/#longer-pipeline

Answer (score 1):

Above answers are correct but i am addressing to them who are newbie here for their simplicity

especially for setting build trigger for pipeline:

Consider you have two Github branches: 1.master, 2.dev,
and Jenkinsfile (where pipeline script is written) and other files are available on each branch

Configure new Pipeline project (for dev branch)

**##1.Code integration with git-plugin and cron based approach**
Prerequisite git plugin should be installed and configure it with your name and email

1. General section.Check checkbox - 'This project is parameterized’ and add Name-SBRANCH Default Value-'refs/remotes/origin/dev'
2. Build triggers section" Check checkbox - 'Poll SCM' and schedule as per need for checking commits e.g. '*/1 * * * *' to check every minute
3. Pipeline definition section.Select - Pipeline script from SCM—> select git—> addRepository URL—>add git credentials—> choose advanced—> add Name- origin, RefSpec- '+refs/heads/dev:refs/remotes/origin/dev'(dev is github branch )—> Branches to build - ${SBRANCH} (Parameter name from ref 1st point)—> Script Path—> Jenkinsfile —> Uncheck Lightweightcheckout
4. Apply—> save

**##2.Code integration: github-plugin and webhook approach**
Prerequisite Github plugin should be installed and Github server should be configured, connection should be tested if not consider following configuration

Configure Github plugin with account on Jenkins

GitHub section Add Github server if not present API URL: https://api.github.com Credentials: Add secret text (Click add button: select type secret text) with value Personal Access Token (Generate it from your Github accounts—> settings—> developer setting—> personal access token—> add token—> check scopes—> copy the token) Test Connection—> Check whether it is connected to your Github account or not Check checkbox with Manage Hooks In advance sub-section just select previous credential for 'shared secret'

Add webhook if not added to your repository by

1. Go to Github Repository setting —> add webhook—> add URL
   http://Public_IP:Jenkins_PORT/github-webhook/
2. Or if you don't have Public_IP use [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/). Install, authenticate, get public IP from command ./ngrok http 80(use your jenkins_port) then add webhook —> add URL http://Ngrok_IP/github-webhook/
3. Test it by delivering payload from webhook page and check whether you get 200 status or not.

If you have Github Pull requests plugin configure it also with published Jenkins URL.

1. General section.Check checkbox - 'Github project' add project URL
   -(github link ending with '.git/')
2. General section.Check checkbox - 'This project is parameterized' and add Name-SBRANCH Default Value-'refs/remotes/origin/dev'
3. Build triggers.section.Check checkbox - 'GitHub hook trigger for GITScm polling'
4. Pipeline def'n section: Select - Pipeline script from SCM—> select git—> addRepository URL—> add git credentials—>choose advanced —>add Name- origin, RefSpec- '+refs/heads/dev:refs/remotes/origin/dev' (dev is github branch ) —> Branches to build - ${SBRANCH} (Parameter name from ref 1.st point)—> Script Path—> Jenkinsfile—> Uncheck Lightweightcheckout
5. Apply—> save

Answer (score 0):

Use the pull request builder plugin:
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/GitHub+pull+request+builder+plugin

It's really straightforward. You can then setup GitHub webhooks to trigger builds.

Answer (score 0):

My solution for a local git server: 
go to your local git server hook directory, ignore the existing update.sample and create a new file literally named as "update", such as:

```
gituser@me:~/project.git/hooks$ pwd
/home/gituser/project.git/hooks
gituser@me:~/project.git/hooks$ cat update
#!/bin/sh
echo "XXX from  update file"
curl -u admin:11f778f9f2c4d1e237d60f479974e3dae9 -X POST http://localhost:8080/job/job4_pullsrc_buildcontainer/build?token=11f778f9f2c4d1e237d60f479974e3dae9

exit 0
gituser@me:~/project.git/hooks$
```

The echo statement will be displayed under your git push result, token can be taken from your jenkins job configuration, browse to find it. If the file "update" is not called, try some other files with the same name without extension "sample".

That's all you need

Answer (score 0):

1. Manage Jenkins/ configure system /GitHub Servers
2. On jenkins job / git credentials and Branch Specifier (give the branch you want to look for pushes)
3. 

[image]

4. Webhook on github

Answer (score 0):

I also had same problem. And this saved me

To filter according to the payload 'ref' tag, optional filter is set in jenkins pipeline job.

[image]

Then applied optional filter on 'ref' variable, to allow only master branch

[image]

or expression could be simply

> refs/heads/master

Now my jenkins job is triggering only when there is a commit to master