# Create a git post-receive trigger (should work for Xamarin Studio on Mac OS X)

Tags: git, jenkins, xamarin.ios, xamarin, continuous-integration

I have a network share on which a GIT repository resides in. On my local machine I have checked out the GIT repository, where I'm working on with Xamarin Studio with the integrated GIT client. Additionally, I have installed Jenkins for continuous integration. This is all working so far.

Now I want to notify Jenkins when something is commited to this repository. In [How can I make Jenkins CI with git trigger on pushes to master?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5784329/how-can-i-make-jenkins-ci-with-git-trigger-on-pushes-to-master) it is stated that I should create a github post-receive trigger after setting the *Poll SCM* option.

The post from [Nav](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21636659/426227) says that I only have to create a `post-commit` file in the `hooks` folder with the content similar to

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# A script which triggers the Jenkins build after a commit.
curl http://localhost:8080/jenkins/git/notifyCommit?url=http://localhost:8080/job/MyJobName/
```

but if I try to open the URL in the browser I get

> HTTP ERROR 404
>
> Problem accessing /jenkins/git/notifyCommit. Reason:
>
> ```
> Not Found
> ```

Now I exchanged the URL for

```
http://yourserver/jenkins/git/notifyCommit?url=<URL of the Git repository>
```

and calling this URL directly in the browser leads to a build. Putting this into the script doesn't trigger a build after a commit. I put the hook into the above mentioned directory on the network share. Putting the script on the local repository also didn't triggered the build.

So how can I create such a git post-receive trigger, which works together with Xamarin Studio?

**Edit:**

Now I changed the permission of the local hook to 755 and really removed the file extension, but the build is not triggered.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know if you fixed this already - it's been a while...

But I was just experiencing the same problem, and found it was due to an incorrect URL:

Try `curl http://localhost:8080/git/notifyCommit` instead (without `jenkins/`).

Comment: My issue was very similar. It turned out that I had forgotten to include the port of 8080 in the URL.