# How to Commit Changes to code on Google Compute Engine?

Tags: node.js, meteor, google-cloud-platform

I am new to Google cloud and I have an application running on nodejs server deployed using Google Compute Engine. It is Javascript based application. 
 But now, when I need to change some frontend code for my app, I am unbale to push the changes to the code. 

I tried to connect it with BitBucket, succeeded but google didn't changed the deployed code base according to change in bitbucket. 
Then I created a google cloud repository and did same thing. I can see my changed code in google cloud repository but still  the code deployed for my app is not showing any reflections of the change? I tried restarting Instance but in vain.

How to change my runnable codebase for app hosted on Google Compute Engine?

Comment: How did you push it up the first time? If it is a meteor app, you have to build it first.

Comment: @Akshat I bundled it in tar.gz file and pushed it to cloud storage.

Comment: What version of meteor did you use prior to the update, Was it pre-0.9.0?

Comment: There is no "Google Cloud Engine". Do you mean Google App Engine? Or Google Compute Engine? Push-to-deploy only works on App Engine, not Compute Engine or Managed VMs (which you would need if you are using Node). Please read the docs carefully at https://cloud.google.com/tools/repo/push-to-deploy.

Comment: I asked for Compute engine. Changed it in original question to avoid confusion. And I know, Push-toDeploy works only on App engine but I want some way to change my code on compute engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Adam says "Push-to-deploy" is supported only on App Engine.

If you want to setup your "Push-to-deploy" solution on compute engine you need to install [Jenkins](https://jenkins-ci.org/) and configure it to "[polling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5784329/how-can-i-make-jenkins-ci-with-git-trigger-on-pushes-to-master)" your Git repo, then Jenkins can run "tasks" after a new commit arrive and deploy what you want!

have fun with continuos integration!

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But unfortunately, meteor apps cannot be deployed using app engine. So, I'm out of option. Anyways, Thanks for the answer!