# Jenkins- separating build and deployment

Tags: git, jenkins, hudson

Can Jenkins be configured to build every time a developer commits a code in git  that will create an artifact, but only deploy when required using the artifact from the build process (but not pull again from git), say once at night.

Comment: I should have mentioned that iam looking for somethign similar to what bamboo offers as build plan and deployment projects.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5784329/how-can-i-make-jenkins-ci-with-git-trigger-on-pushes-to-master ... check this it might help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. I suggest that you setup two jobs.

1. Your CI job which polls your source code and runs at every detected commit
2. A second job which runs on daily schedule and uses the [Jenkins Copy Artifact plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin) to copy into its workarea the last available artifact from the first job, and deploys it.

In the second job you can use the [Conditional Build Step plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Conditional+BuildStep+Plugin#ConditionalBuildStepPlugin-Conditionalstep%28single%29) to skip the deployment if the first job status is FAILURE.

Comment: Any luck with this issue? You haven't accepted the answer yet ;-)