# Jenkins and Gitlab sensitive trigger

Tags: jenkins, build, continuous-integration, gitlab, devops

I'm about use Jenkins as my CI for my .NET (Mostly ASP, sometimes UWP and .NET core) projects which are currently hosted on Gitlab as private projects.

I configured stuff and everything seems to work, but the fact is that if anyone pushes anything in any branch, the build process starts! It's so annoying, isn't it?

I was about to configure Jenkins in a way that it becomes sensitive to a special branch (such as 'master' or 'production') push or being sensitive to a special commit message(ex: build the project if commit message includes 'build') to build the project in that case, but I couldn't find a way so failed in that level!

Also I googled around and I saw [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5784329/how-can-i-make-jenkins-ci-with-git-trigger-on-pushes-to-master) but I couldn't find out any way for my situation.

Is there anyway to do this on Jenkins? If not, is there any other CI (build automation) and DevOps tool that can be a good fit for me?