# Is there any pipeline for CI/CD from GitHub to Cloud Foundry during commits

Tags: github, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, git-commit, cloud-foundry

My microservice code is in GitHub. I want to automate the CI/CD on pivotal cloud foundry whenever there is a commit in my remote repository of GitHub. Is there any pipeline or hook available in GitHub which can be used out of box to achieve this.

Comment: Are you using specific CI/CD software or just asking in general?  Concourse CI has resources to pull from Github & deploy to CF, so it would be fairly easy to set it up to deploy your code on each commit.  https://concourse-ci.org/included-resources.html

Comment: If you are using Jenkins for CI/CD pipeline, you can use `GitHub hook trigger for GITScm polling`. Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5784329/how-can-i-make-jenkins-ci-with-git-trigger-on-pushes-to-master for more details

Comment: Please take a look at [Spring Cloud Pipelines](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-pipelines). You can get the samples for Concourse and Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

Teere should be now with [GitHub Actions](https://github.com/features/actions)

- either through their [new included CI/CD](https://github.blog/2019-08-08-github-actions-now-supports-ci-cd/) (August 2019)
- or through their [GitHub Action for Cloud Foundry CLI](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/github-action-for-cloud-foundry) ([`louisthomas/cloud-foundry-cli-action`](https://github.com/louisthomas/cloud-foundry-cli-action), Feb. 2019)