# How to trigger the build jenkins if master branch has changed?

Tags: jenkins, triggers, webhooks, gitea

I have a freestyle job with Gitea scm.
I setted webhook on Gitea but when others branch change, jenkins will rebuilds once.
How can I trigger the build on pushed to master branch only?

Answer (score 1):

I may have fallen into the same trap : I configured Gitea with a webhook pointing to `https://jenkins/job/myJob/build?token=abcdef...` which starts the job whatever the circumstances.

The correct way seems to point to the git notifyCommit URL : `https://jenkins/git/notifyCommit?url=git@code.example.org:ltorvalds/kernel.git` and use the SCM polling functionnality :

- On Jenkins, at `job/myJob/configure` > *Build Triggers*, uncheck *Trigger builds remotely* and check *Poll SCM*, leaving the schedule empty.
- Be also sure to specify your branch (for example : `refs/heads/master`) in *Source Code Management* > *Git* > *Branches to build*.

If the Jenkins job is private, you can add the username/token in the webhook URL like that : `https://username:ApiToken@jenkins/git/notifyCommit?url=git@code.example.org:ltorvalds/kernel.git`. See https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API

More infos / duplicate of [How can I make Jenkins CI with Git trigger on pushes to master?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5784329/how-can-i-make-jenkins-ci-with-git-trigger-on-pushes-to-master)